# Google+ post or "+1" something using Google+ API

Tags: api, google-plus

I see that Google started to offer some alpha API.

Is there any way to post something in Google+ using Google+ API? If not the same way as for Facebook and Facebook SDK, at least something similar.

I would like to implement it in a native iOS/Android code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. I expect that similar to how there is no way to implement a *Like* via an API, there will never be an API to allow sending a +1 via an API. It is expected and intended to only ever be done by direct action by a user, NOT something that can be manipulated by a programmer to artificially inflate their rankings.

Comment: There may be a good reason not allowing "Likes" to be automated, but I don't see any reason why they don't allow third party Apps to post.

Comment: +1 will probably never be automated, but posting will probably come in the not-too-distant future. The first revision of the Google+ api was just released and that doesn't include posting but I'm sure the API used by the Google+ Android/iOS apps will be available for third party use soon.